# is $(\bigtriangledown . A)B = (B.\bigtriangledown )A$

Tags: vector-analysis

can you tell me is $(\bigtriangledown . A)B = (B.\bigtriangledown )A$?

I know that $(\bigtriangledown. \omega)r = (r.\bigtriangledown) \omega$

there is a problem, given that velocity v=r×ωv=r×ω then prove that ω=(1/2)▽×vω=(1/2)▽×v while proving this i got (▽.ω)r=(r.▽)ω(▽.ω)r=(r.▽)ω so i was thinking wther this is general axiom for any 2 vectors A and B?

Comment: What is $A, B, \omega, r$? What have you tried, because it looks just like a verifiable calculation to me?

Comment: there is a problem,
given that velocity $v=r \times \omega$ then prove that $\omega = (1/2) \bigtriangledown  \times v$
while proving this i got $(\bigtriangledown . \omega) r = (r. \bigtriangledown ) \omega$
so i was thinking wther this is general axiom for any 2 vectors A and B?

Comment: ${\bf v}={\bf \omega}\times {\bf r}$, not ${\bf r}\times {\bf \omega}$.